# Python kivy maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Please look at my code.
Running this code will cause a recursive error.
Please tell me if there is an efficient way of writing that will not result in a recursive error.
Also, sys.setrecursionlimit (10000) caused a crash.

```
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if touch.y > self.touch_pos_y:
        if self.anim_search_direction == 'up':
            self.anim_search_direction = 'down'
            anim_s_h_u_1 = Animation(opacity=0, duration=.6, t='out_expo')
            anim_s_h_u_2 = Animation(height=sp(40), duration=.6, t='out_expo')
            anim_s_h_u_3 = Animation(height=sp(40), duration=.6, t='out_expo')
            anim_s_h_u_4 = Animation(height=sp(40), duration=.6, t='out_expo')
            anim_s_h_u_1.start(self.a)
            anim_s_h_u_2.start(self.b)
            anim_s_h_u_3.start(self.c)
            anim_s_h_u_4.start(self.d)
    elif touch.y < self.touch_pos_y:
        if self.anim_search_direction == 'down':
            self.anim_search_direction = 'up'
            anim_s_h_u_1 = Animation(opacity=1, duration=.6, t='out_expo')
            anim_s_h_u_2 = Animation(height=sp(66), duration=.6, t='out_expo')
            anim_s_h_u_3 = Animation(height=sp(80), duration=.6, t='out_expo')
            anim_s_h_u_4 = Animation(height=sp(66), duration=.6, t='out_expo')
            anim_s_h_u_1.start(self.a)
            anim_s_h_u_2.start(self.b)
            anim_s_h_u_3.start(self.c)
            anim_s_h_u_4.start(self.d)
```

TRACEBAK IS HERE AND LOOP THIS.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 478, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (kivy\properties.c:5572)
    File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 516, in kivy.properties.Property.set (kivy\properties.c:6405)
    File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 571, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch (kivy\properties.c:7105)
    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:14035)
    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1131, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy\_event.c:13193)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 548, in _update_effect_bounds
 self._update_effect_y_bounds()
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 540, in _update_effect_y_bounds
 self.effect_y.value = self.effect_y.min * self.scroll_y
    File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 478, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (kivy\properties.c:5572)
    File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 516, in kivy.properties.Property.set (kivy\properties.c:6405)
    File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 571, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch (kivy\properties.c:7105)
    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:14035)
    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1131, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy\_event.c:13193)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\effects\dampedscroll.py", line 104, in on_value
self.scroll = self.value
    File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 478, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (kivy\properties.c:5572)
    File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 516, in kivy.properties.Property.set (kivy\properties.c:6405)
    File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 571, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch (kivy\properties.c:7105)
    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:14035)
    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1131, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy\_event.c:13193)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 576, in _update_effect_y
self.scroll_y = -sy
```

Comment: we need to see what function is recurring I think

Comment: Could you add the entire error message you're getting (with traceback) to your post?

Comment: this is error code. RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: And when remove line of code 'anim_s_h_u_4', not happen this error.

Comment: I tried various exploration.
This def is a function of the kivy library, and it is an event when touching and moving.
This def moves every time move while touching.
My problem was predicting memory eating too much as it touched and moved for a longer time.

In order to solve it, you may need to write "enable on_touch_move only for a few seconds" code.


I will check from now.

Comment: sorry but that is not the full traceback, please add more